# Confusing Output to a HashMap iterable from input in Rust

Tags: rust

This program takes as input a sentence " Add name to dept", passes the string into a function that splits the string by whitespace into a vector that then is inserted into a hashmap that is suppose to retain the values of name and dept, which it does for 1 input. On the second input only the first word "Add" is printed. Are there any glaring missteps that may cause this odd output?

```
use std::io; 
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut db: HashMap<String,String>  = HashMap::new();
    loop {
        println!("'Add <name> to <department>'");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Not input");
        add_to_hashmap(&input, &mut db);
        }
}
fn add_to_hashmap(input: &String, db: &mut HashMap<String,String>){
    let v: Vec<&str> = input.split(" ").collect();
    db.insert(v[1].to_string(),v[3].to_string());
    for (name, dept) in db{ 
        println!("{}, {}", name, dept);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Investigation

To diagnose this I added a [`dbg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html) call to check the value of `input` each time `add_to_hashmap` is called.

```
let v: Vec<&str> = dbg!(input).split(" ").collect();
```

The first time it prints:

```
'Add <name> to <department>'
Add john to math
[src/main.rs:13] input = "Add john to math\n"
john, math
```

The second time:

```
'Add <name> to <department>'
Add bill to science
[src/main.rs:13] input = "Add john to math\nAdd bill to science\n"
john, math
```

###### Diagnosis

`input` isn't being cleared. `read_line` doesn't erase the input buffer; it just appends to it.

In the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) you can see that the example code clears the buffer after each call:

> ```
> use std::io::{self, BufRead};
>
> let mut cursor = io::Cursor::new(b"foo\nbar");
> let mut buf = String::new();
>
> // cursor is at 'f'
> let num_bytes = cursor.read_line(&mut buf)
>     .expect("reading from cursor won't fail");
> assert_eq!(num_bytes, 4);
> assert_eq!(buf, "foo\n");
> buf.clear();
>
> // cursor is at 'b'
> let num_bytes = cursor.read_line(&mut buf)
>     .expect("reading from cursor won't fail");
> assert_eq!(num_bytes, 3);
> assert_eq!(buf, "bar");
> buf.clear();
>
> // cursor is at EOF
> let num_bytes = cursor.read_line(&mut buf)
>     .expect("reading from cursor won't fail");
> assert_eq!(num_bytes, 0);
> assert_eq!(buf, "");
> ```

Comment: Thank You so much for taking the time. I'm new to Rust and now the program works perfectly! On to the next chapter....